# Anyway to get Node.js to optionally validate certificates against windows certificate store?

Tags: node.js, ssl

We have self signed certs setup with a trusted ca cert in windows cert store. Node throws errors about not being able to verify the validity of self signed cert understandably because that trusted ca cert is not in the store that node uses.

My question isn't whether I can build something with node that hosts a site, using a cert from windows cert store (I believe there are packages that will let you do that). My question is whether there is anyway to have node check the windows cert store as well as the local store, so as to not have to export and re-import certs.

I know windows never seemed to be a first class citizen for node support, but you'd think because windows default location for storing certs is the windows certificate store, that might be something node should support.

Thanks!